# Jquery validation on fileinput bootstrap plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using [Fileinput Bootstrap](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) for `file` input fields. Following is my code:-

**HTML**

```
<input id="input-upload-img1" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" name="img1" accept='image/*,video/*'>
<input id="input-upload-img2" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" name="img2" accept='image/*,video/*'>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $('#input-upload-img1').fileinput({
        initialPreview: [
            "<img src='img1' class='file-preview-image' alt='Desert'>",
        ]
    });
</script>
```

So, now I've an initial preview on one of my input field having id `input-upload-img1` and no preview on the other input field.

Now I apply jQuery validation of the input field

```
img1: {
    require_from_group: [1, '.file'],
    accept: "image/*"
},
img2: {
    require_from_group: [1, '.file'],
    accept: "image/*"
}
```

But, when I submit the form, it still shows the error of saying `Atleast 1 field is required`. Why is it happening when I've already provided an image in the first input box? Also, If I browse separately again. it will work.

Why jQuery validation is showing error when initial preview field has already been provided.

**Following is my dummy code:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.3.1/css/fileinput.min.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="input-upload-img1" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" name="img1" accept='image/*'>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.3.1/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#input-upload-img1").fileinput({
        initialPreview: [
            "<img src='http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg' class='file-preview-image' width=20% height=20%>"
        ]
    });

    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            img1: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.file'],
                accept: "image/*,video/*",
                filesize: 100000000
            }
        }
    })

</script>
</html>
```

As you can see, there's initially an image in the input field. But when I submit the form, it returns an error saying `Please fill at least 1 of these field`, since there's no file selected. How can I overcome this?

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ghnx7uo/). But it somehow doesnt display the initial preview of the image, hence I recommend you to copy-paste this code and run it on your own system.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  I can't submit the form until I select at least one image:  https://jsfiddle.net/g7ugaejs/

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I should be allowed to submit the form because an initial preview has already been provided for one of the input file field.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused about what the `require_from_group` rule means.  The rule says that at least one field must be completed.  As soon as you [select a file for upload, the rule is fully satisfied and the form is allowed to submit](https://jsfiddle.net/g7ugaejs/). Otherwise, I don't understand the issue as you're describing it.

Comment: So basically I want that when I've set an initial preview, then jquery-validation should skip the file input required validation.

Comment: How can I write such piece of code in jquery?

Comment: Is *"set an initial preview"* not the same as selecting a file for upload?

Comment: No. It isnt. That's the main issue. How can I handle this that when-ever `initialPreview` is set on any particular group, then jquery should skip `require_from_group` validation on that particular group.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, triggering validation programmatically depends on the methods provided by the Fileinput plugin.  **Is there a Fileinput method that fires when the "initial preview is set"?**

Comment: Is this closer to what you want?:  https://jsfiddle.net/kbt2eddL/

Comment: Thanks @Sparky for providing the jsfiddle link. However, it still doesn't solve my issue. So, in you jsfiddle link whenever I submit the form it says `Please fill at least 1 of these fields.`. Inspite of the images already been provided, it still returns the error. I just want to skip this error if the images are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Fileinput Bootstrap for file input fields.

I suspect that the original `input` element is hidden, therefore, the various user events that would normally trigger validation are not occurring.  I'm not familiar with the `Fileinput` plugin, so you may need to do one or both of the following:

1. Make sure you have the `ignore` option set to `[]`.  This will ensure that the hidden input elements will be validated no matter what.
2. You'll need to programmatically trigger validation when you interact with the `Fileinput` element.  If this plugin provides a callback function that will fire whenever a file is selected, put `$('[name="img1"], [name="img2"]').valid();` inside of this function.

Comment: Well, I read from its Github repo issues, that preview is just a display ... It does not populate the file input. How can I handle this in the code?

Comment: Since, I'm using `require_from_group` on the file input field, shall I over-ride this function. Sorry for asking a naive question. I'm not well-versed with the jquery. Request you to please provide a suitable demo. Thanks.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast, before asking me to construct a demo, I will ask the same from you.  Since I'm not familiar with `Fileinput` plugin, please provide a jsFiddle demo showing the issue.

Comment: @sparky- I've updated my question with a dummy demo and the jsfiddle link. Kindly have a look. Thanks